# Passing a vector<vector<int> > pointer to a argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Okay, so I'm trying to pass a pointer to a argument like this.

```
void function(vector<vector<int> > *i){
 vector<int> j;
 j.push_back(5);
 i->push_back(j);
}
```

And call it with `function(&i)`

But when I do it says i[0][0] is 0 and not 5.

Why is this happening?

Edit:

```
int main(){ 
vector<vector<int> > test;
function(&test);
cout << test[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Post more code.. the code which calls this function

Comment: Can you post the calling code ?

Comment: It should not be happening, so you must have initilized i[0] from the outside somewhere ... what is i.size() at the time of the printout? I ran the same code and got 5!

Comment: @Cyan: Your example does not compile. You do not initialize `test` (it is a pointer). Then you pass the *address of that pointer* to your function, which is not what it requires.

Comment: @Cyan: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/8U05r).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
void f(vector<vector<int> > *i)
{
   vector<int> j;
   j.push_back(5);
   i->push_back(j);
}
vector<vector<int> > i;
f(&i);
cout << i[0][0];
```

Output:

```
5
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/hzCtV

Or alternatively, you can also pass by reference as illustrated here : http://ideone.com/wA2tc

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling your function as `function(test)` and not `function(&test)` as the second one will not compile. Your code in `main` is wrong. You should declare test as `vector<vector<int> > test;` (without `*`). At its current form, you have just defined *pointer* to a vector without actually allocating the vector itself. If you try to dereference this pointer (you are trying to do `i->push_back()` you will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: You are still having the problem or it is working as expected now?

Answer (score 0):

At least on my machine, this gives me 5!

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::vector;

void vf(vector<vector<int> > * i) {
   vector<int> j;
   j.push_back(5);
   i->push_back(j);
}

int main() {
   vector<vector<int> > j;
   vf(&j);
   printf("c: %d\n",j[0][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use references instead of pointers unless NULL is an acceptable value for the pointer. By doing this you can avoid having to test for a NULL pointer condition and it helps clean up the syntax.